# tease out significance

Tags: r, regression

Say I have search data like this

`AvgCost   QualityScore   SearchShare`

`3.12      6               0.6364`

Where AvgCost is a continuous numerical variable, qualityScore is a categorical variable with values 1-10, and SearchShare is a percentage...I am wondering how to tease out the effect Avgcost and QualityScore have as well as whether they are too related to be both included. I'm also wondering what kinds of regressions besides simple linear regressions can be run on data sets where I have these sorts of variables i.e. categorical and numerical explanatory variables and a percentage response variable.

I have done some obvious things, like check `cor()` between qualityScore and AvgCost as well as do a simple linear regression. I looked at the `relaimpo` package, not sure if that's what I need.

Anyway, thanks very much for any help!

Comment: To be clear, you have >1 value for each variable, right? How is it that `SearchShare` is a percentage? Is it that there are a certain number of searches, of which the given percentage contain some specific term? Do you know the number of searches & the number w/ the search term?

Comment: Yes there is > 1 value in each variable, just wanted to provide an example. And the SearchShare is the share of views that search term got in a Google search

Comment: Do you know how many searches there were for each observation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting too deep in some analysis, I suggest some simple plots, e.g., scatterplots of each pair of variables to see if they are related linearly. If they are, then linear regression is about all that you need. If `AvgCost` and `QualityScore` are strongly correlated, then it may be that only one of them is needed to predict the response -- or even that if both are used as predictors, neither one is significant while either one individually is.

If there are nonlinear relationships, then perhaps transformations of one or more variables -- such as square roots, logs, or reciprocals -- could help make things more linear.

You mention that `QualityScore` is categorical; and indeed, it could be treated as a factor (aka class variable) in the regression. And that may be suggested by your plots as well. However, it seems to me that `QualityScore` is better described as *discrete* rather than *categorical*. It is not a problem to have discrete predictors in a regression equation.